# Java 8: How get a property from an object in a list where the other property of object must match with input

Tags: java, list, filter, java-8, java-stream

```
class Person{
     String Name;
     String Id;
    }
```

I have a list of person. I want to get the id of a person where the Name matches with input, I know it can be done by using filter but in my case, name is always unique so I get only one ID back. Please let me know if there is any other efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the name is unique, you could use the short-circuiting terminal operation `findFirst` after the `filter`. This would allow the stream processing to stop as soon as a match is encountered.

```java
return list.stream()
           .filter(p -> p.getName().equals(input))
           .findFirst() // Optional<Person> is returned
           .map(Person::getId)
           .orElse(null);// if no matching name is found
```

Comment: Note that this is a linear (O(N)) lookup and depending on how big the list is and how often the lookup is performed it could become problematic.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to query on name many times you could keep a map around that maps a Person to a name (and that's assuming your names are indeed unique).

```
Map<String, Person> byName = new HashMap<>();
yourList.forEach(person -> byName.put(person.name, person));
```

and then lookup the person directly by name:

```
Person person = byName.get("a name");
if (person != null) {
...
}
```